# Find number of variables on different levels within a dataframe using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code and am unsure how this would be written using `dplyr`

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  b = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2),
  c = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4),
  d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4),
  e = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5)
)

n = 100
results=data.frame(levels=double(),amount=double())
for(i in 1:n){
  r <- df %>% select_if(~n_distinct(.)==i)
  if(dim(r)[2]>0){
    results=rbind(results,data.frame(levels=i,amount=dim(r)[2]))
  }
}
results
```

which outputs

```
  levels amount
1      2      1
2      3      1
3      4      1
4      5      2
```

The use of the `for` loop and `if` statement makes me think there must be a
nicer approach though, or at least, one that makes use of dplyr instead.

## edit

Data frame with different types

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  b = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2),
  c = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4),
  d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4),
  e = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5),
  f = c('a','b','a','a','a','a','a','b')
)
```

Comment: It would be better both for answerers and future readers that you explain what you want to do rather than have us try to infer it from your code.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper the output desired is included in the post? The code works, the question is how to do it in dplyr, which part is unclear?

Comment: I mean that you should describe in plain English the transformation that happens from your input to your output, and not have use figure out what is n or r, level, amount... It's great that you provided input and output

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper sorry, tried to be brief I didn't mean to be unclear

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
 group_by(name) %>%
 summarise(n_levels = n_distinct(value)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 count(n_levels)

  n_levels     n
     <int> <int>
1        2     1
2        3     1
3        4     1
4        5     2
```

Comment: I'm getting an error : `could not find function "pivot_longer` , i have tidyverse installed, anything obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: Please try to update `tidyr`. It is from the newest version :)

Comment: ah ok - I've updated thanks. It seems i overlooked that I have mixed data types in my example. I'm not sure whether in this case I should leave it as is (for the question is self contained) or adapt. The other answer (using stack()) works for my solution, but that's not what I originally wrote

Comment: You can load your data by adding `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` and then using `df %>%
 mutate_if(is.numeric, as.character) before pivot_longer()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    summarise_all(.funs = function(x) length(unique(x))) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%  #OR gather %>%
    count(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach could be :

```
stack(table(sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))))

#  ind values
#1   2      1
#2   3      1
#3   4      1
#4   5      2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better way to do what you want. Using `dplyr` and `purr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  b = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2),
  c = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4),
  d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4),
  e = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5)
)

map_df(df, function(d){
              data.frame(level = n_distinct(d))
           }) %>% 
group_by(level) %>% 
summarise(amount = n())
```